# Convert String array to Integer

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I want to convert a string array to integer but Integers parseInt() exception - Unknown Source occurs. I am using `string.split()` and a scanner.

java Code I'm using:

```
...{
String in = "03-02-2014 ;03-02-2014 ;LOW VALUE ;-150.65 ;11.5 ;3301.52 ;3301.52" ;
Scanner s = new Scanner(in);

String line = s.toString();
String[] parts = line.split(" ;");

//Getting First Date
String date1 = parts[0];  
String[] daysDate = date1.split("-");
int dia= new Integer (Integer.parseInt(daysDate[0]));
int mes= new Integer (Integer.parseInt(daysDate[1]));
int ano= new Integer (Integer.parseInt(daysDate[2]));

//Get second date
String valueDateStri = parts[1];  
String[] valueDateSplit = valueDateStri.split("-");
int vdia=Integer.parseInt(valueDateSplit[0]);
int vmes=Integer.parseInt(valueDateSplit[1]);
int vano=Integer.parseInt(valueDateSplit[2]);

//Get String Description
String desc = parts[2]; 

//Get Double values
double drafT = Double.parseDouble(parts[3]);       //Draft
double crediT = Double.parseDouble(parts[4]);      //credit
double accBalance = Double.parseDouble(parts[5]);  //acountingBalance
double avbBalance = Double.parseDouble(parts[6]);  //avaiableBalance
```

**The EXCEPTION:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\.][decimal separator=\,][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q"

    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `String[] parts = line.split(" ;");` do `String[] parts = in.split(" ;");`  As you said, you are using split instead of the scanner; what you actually did was you used the scanner, converted the scanner instance to a String (instead of the value), and tried to parse that.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the issue is that you call the `split()` function on the scanner's `toString()` result.

If you wanted to use a scanner, you can set a deliminator like so:

```
s.useDeliminator(" ;");
```

Then, you can just keep looping through the values while the scanner still has input.

```
while(s.hasNext()){
    final String nextValue = s.next();
    // Parse nextValue
}
```

---

You could just boycott the `Scanner` altogether though, and just do the following:

```
String in = "03-02-2014 ;03-02-2014 ;LOW VALUE ;-150.65 ;11.5 ;3301.52 ;3301.52" ;
String[] parts = in.split(" ;");
```

Though, be careful when parsing. Especially if the input is going to change. The way you have it set up might lead to issues if you need to parse unique inputs.